# How to embed a document into quill js editor?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file-upload, quill, react-quill

I want to embed a document inside the quill editor. To illustrate, a user can click a custom document icon on the quill toolbar. When the user clicks the custom document icon, a file picker opens up. Then the user can select a file from a file picker and upload that document. So that, the document should be inserted inside the quill editor, and when a user clicks the document he/she can download the document.

what I meant by "the document should be embedded inside the editor"?
I mean after selecting a file, The user should be able to view a custom blot (or something, IDK). That separated from the other text. I should insert a document icon before the document name to distinguish it from normal text.

Where to place the document?
I should place the document at the current cursor position of the quill editor.

Thank You.

Comment: You find a solution to this? I have a simliar need.